# How to getText() of an element with 2 values

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

The html element is the following[image]

I want to get the value "7.99"

I have tried the this:

```
String price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='inventory_item_price']")).getText();
```

But the price is "$7.99"

Comment: Have you tried `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='inventory_item_price']")).getText().replace("$", "");`?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see yourself, the element contains 2 pieces of text "$" and "7.99".
`.getText()` method returns the entire text of the element, that is "$7.99".
If you want to remove the "$" sign you can simply remove it from the result as following:

```
String price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='inventory_item_price']")).getText().replace("$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JS you can do something like this  :

Why JS ?

if $ changes to some other currency your script will start failing (if you are using the replace method)

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='inventory_item_price']"));
String text = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;", elem);
System.out.println(text);
```